# SQLite - LEFT JOIN

Tags: sqlite

I need to make a query like this:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.column 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
```

But it's not working. If I try the same query but replacing the first part -- >

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
```

it works fine. I need to bring all the columns from table1. How can I make it without specifing all of them?

Comment: What is the error ? Don't you have the same column name in both tables ?

Comment: Using  `SELECT *` or `SELECT table.*` in production is a bad practice. Consider to specify all columns explicitly. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: Yes, it's the same name. And there's no error, I get all table1 columns but not the one I need. This is the real query

SELECT property.*, ubication.name  FROM property LEFT JOIN ubication ON ubication.id = property.ubication

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5dc3b/1/0). Don't keep your table structure a secret!

Comment: grat, thanks! I didnt show the structure cause it's really big and I was at work! haha, thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have the same column name in `table1` and `table2`, here is the solution for not specifying all the column name of `table1` :

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.column as my_column_name_no_in_table1
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
```

If the column names of `table1` and `table2` are all different, you can use :

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
```

But as said in the [peterm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1920232/peterm)'s comment, it is not a good practice in production. Now, do as you want! ;)

Comment: I'm still getting the same columns as I did before!

Comment: And you can give us also the table structure if you want more help.

Comment: SELECT property.*, ubication.name  FROM property 
LEFT JOIN ubication ON property.ubication = ubication.id

That's it, there's no error shown in that query, but I'm getting all property columns but not the ubication one, my english sucks sorry

Comment: Well, that's normal you don't get all the ubication columns, you just select the `name` column of ubication.

Comment: yea but I don't get that, I don't get any ubication columns! I only get property columns, its weird that if I change the "SELECT property.*" for a "property.anyColumn", it works!

Comment: Mmmmh, your problem is not clear. If you select a column, you'll have it in your result set. Tell us how you query your database.